# In java, why does it not matter if we use a class in a code before declaring it?

Tags: java, oop

In Java, often main methods are written above (or at least I do so) and in these methods, objects are created even if their respective classes are declared way below. Why does it not result in a compilation error? I know java is not procedural but I never found an answer for this.

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    baby1 obj1 = new baby1();
    baby2 obj2 = new baby2();
}

class baby1 
 {
    //some code
 }
class baby2
 {
   //some code
 }
```

Comment: Because the language allows for such forward references. It is simply a design decision.

Comment: Java uses a [multi-pass compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-pass_compiler).

Comment: Actually, why would it? In C, this problem exists because the compiler requires that everything can be analysed in only one pass. Java is more recent and the designers of this language did not have the same memory constraints than when C was designed.

Comment: This is the way compiler works! Java language doesn't require that things needs to be "declared/defined" before being used, just to be declared/defined somewhere.

Comment: *"I know java is not procedural..."* There's no reason a procedural language couldn't do this as well -- and indeed, some do.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder is that not opposed to the procedural ideology? "Each code is executed step by step" and all that

Comment: @AsmaRahimAliJafri: This isn't about execution, it's about compilation.

Answer (score 6):

Java uses Multiple Passes for Name Resolution. The first pass is  "Definition Pass" where it scans the source program and stores **classes**, **fields** and **methods** in a table. In the next pass ("Resolution Pass"), if it encountered a class, it *looks up* for the class in the table created in the previous pass. If the class is there, it continues otherwise it throws an error.

But this doesn't happen for Local Variable Declaration. You can't use a local variable before it has been declared.